# Evaluating $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-(x+iy)^2}dx$? For a fixed $y \in \mathbb{R}$,

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, contour-integration, gaussian-integral

> For a fixed $y \in \mathbb{R}$, how do I evaluate $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-(x+iy)^2}dx$$

It seems like a Gaussian integral. The integration is really over a shift of the real line. Let's look at the function $f(z)=e^{-z^2}e^{i2bz}$ for a real number $b$. Without loss of generality assume that $b \gt 0$. If $b \lt 0$, we draw the contour below the $x$-axis. Since $f$ is entire, the integration of $f$ over the contour [image] is $0$. Now along the vertical segments $II$ and $IV$, $|f(z)|=\left|e^{-(\pm R+iy)^2}e^{i2b(R+iy)}\right|=e^{-R^2+y^2}e^{-2by} \le e^{-R^2}e^{\tau^2+2b\tau}$. Thus the integrals $\left|\int_{II}f \right|$ and $\left|\int_{IV}f \right|$ are bounded by $\tau e^{-R^2}e^{\tau^2+2b\tau}$. Now with $\tau$ and $b$ fixed, this goes to $0$ as $R \to \infty$.

Thus, letting $R \to \infty$, the integral along the contour becomes $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}e^{2bix}dx-e^{\tau^2-2b\tau}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}e^{2i(b-\tau)x}dx=0$$

This holds for all $b$ and $\tau$. Letting $b=\tau$, we have 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}e^{2bix}dx=e^{-b^2}\sqrt{\pi}$$

Using this we get that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-(x+iy)^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$$

How do I proceed to evaluate this without using Contour Integration? Hints and comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since $e^{-z^2}$ is an entire function, from the residue theorem it follows that such integral is constant for any $y$, and it equals $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: It is strange that I met this problem in the review queues waiting for closing

Comment: @GuyFsone I didn't know how to proceed except for contour integration. Since I didn't add enough details, it seems that people tried to close it down

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam you may add what you did here otherwise you post is going to be close soon

Comment: @Did,NCh I have reworded the question

Comment: @John Doe, Cameron Williams, MyGlasses.. Can this be opened now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the factor $e^{-x^2}$ the function 
$$y\mapsto f(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-(x+iy)^2}dx $$

is smooth (**please check it with usual routine**). Moreover since $e^{-x^2}\to 0,~as~|x|\to\infty$ we have

$$ f'(y)=-\int_{\mathbb{R}} 2i(x+iy)e^{-(x+iy)^2}dx = -i \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(e^{-(x+iy)^2}\right)dx = \left[e^{-(x+iy)^2}\right]_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} =0$$
Hence $f$ is constant and therefore for all $y\in \Bbb R$

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-(x+iy)^2}dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: @JohnDoe yes I like this way. It is very powerful when one needs to show that the Fourier of Gaussian is a Gaussian. this is how I usually prove it

Comment: @GuyFsone This is an awesome proof. I just have to check that the function is differentiable and the differentiation can be taken inside